# Android: Button with two images | alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have created this button programmatically and I am able to set the `icon` on the by using below code

[image]

```
Drawable icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconResourceId);
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);
```

Now, I want to have another image (`icon`) on the right top corner, please see the below image:

[image]

I have tried to add both images, by using below code:

```
Drawable icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconResourceId);
Drawable icon2 = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconResourceId2);
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, icon2, null);
```

and, I am getting below results:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me, how can I align it to the right top corner?

Comment: Try using Relative Imageview on button and set image to imagview

Comment: RelativeLayout will do the trick

Comment: Make a Layer-list in xml containing both the background of the button and the new icon on top. Set that layer-list as the background of your button

Comment: @chappie112, i have to achieve it programmatically!

Comment: Well you can just replace the background programmatically. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @chappie112, i think you did not understand my question. :)

Comment: I think you mean that you currently have a button which you make programmatically, you probably set the text and left Drawable as well as the custom red/orange background with rounded corners. And what you the question is how you align the yellow crown image to the top right of the button?

Comment: Yes bro, i want to keep both images, one on the left side and one on the right top corner :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like this where `btn_background` is the background you have at the moment

```
    Button button = new Button(this);
    Drawable icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconResourceId);
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);
    button.setText("Test");

    if (hasNewUpdates()) {
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_background_with_icon);
    } else {
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_background);
    }
```

And this is how the `btn_background_with_icon` will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_background"/>
    <item android:gravity="right" android:bottom="72dp" android:drawable="@drawable/ico_info"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: You are still not getting my point, background of button is created by gradient color and these two images are separate images, if the user is VIP then it will show the both images, crown image (top right corner image) & the button icon (left side image), else it will show the button icon (left side image)

Comment: actually i want to align the crown image to the right top corner!

Comment: But that is what this code does (just change the hasNewUpdates() with your VIP check), but instead of adding the crown image via compoundDrawable (where we can't align the image) we do it via the background. Also it doesn't matter if your button has a gradient or not. It can be anything from a image to a xml Shape with gradient.